# How to return an element value from one branch based on an element value while in a for-each loop

Tags: xslt

I need to update the xsl below so that the user group in the output is not "true", but the value of the user group name.

For example: for the "Summary Report" for grid name: "grid01" I need the xsl to reach over to the gridmappings element and for the report and return the user group name: "managers"

Is that possible?

Apologies, the xml and xsl is not displaying correctly in the preview pane but there should be enough to convey what I need to do.

Thank you
Rod

```
     <top>
```

`enter code here`    
    
      Summary Report
      
        
          grid01
        
        
          grid02
        
      
      
        
          grid01
          managers
        
        
          grid02
          office admin

```
<report>
  <reportname>Detail Report</reportname>
  <grids>
    <grid>
      <gridname>grid01</gridname>
    </grid>
    <grid>
      <gridname>grid02</gridname>
    </grid>
  </grids>
  <gridmappings>
    <gridmap>
      <gridname>grid01</gridname>
      <usergroup>east coast managers</usergroup>
    </gridmap>
    <gridmap>
      <gridname>grid02</gridname>
      <usergroup>west coast managers</usergroup>
     </gridmap>
  </gridmappings>
   </report>
 </reports>
 </top>
```

xsl:

``

```
<html>
  <body>
 <h2>Report Metadata</h2>

  <table border="1">
   <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
     <th>Report Name</th>
      <th>Grid Name</th>
  <th>User Group</th>
   </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="/top/reports/report/grids/grid">      
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::report/reportname"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="gridname"/></td>

            <!-- <td><xsl:value-of select="user_group_goes_here"/></td> -->
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::report/gridmappings/gridmap/gridname=gridname"  /></td>

        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>


 </table>

  </body>
  </html>

 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and make it readable. Also include the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, that was my first time posting here.  The online editing was not acting as I was expecting.

      <top>
   
element needs to go before the 

      <report> 
   
   element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach out to elements in different hierarchy using parent axis:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Report Metadata</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Report Name</th>
                    <th>Grid Name</th>
                    <th>User Group</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="top/reports/report/grids/grid">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../../reportname"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="gridname"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../../gridmappings/gridmap[gridname = current()/gridname]/usergroup"  />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="../../gridmappings/gridmap[gridname = current()/gridname]/usergroup"  />

Comment: Thank you, you did answer the question and I'll do that after I submit this question.  

The actual xml is a bit more complex, I simplified it for illustration purposes.  I need to get an child element of the grandparent of the current() node and if I try this I get an error:  

     <xsl:value-of select="../../gridmappings/gridmap[gridname = ../../gridname]/usergroup"  />    
  
  
Thanks for your help

Comment: I found the answer to getting an element relative to a grandfather -- insead of using current()   :

       <xsl:value-of select="current()/parent::*/parent::*/Name"  />

Comment: .. is short form of parent::*